# Todoist in Github Readme

Tags: github, readme, todoist

Please, I would like some help to put on Todoist in my Github readme.md.
I'm following the tutorial [Todoist Readme](https://github.com/abhisheknaiidu/todoist-readme) but I have a problem with API key in this point:

```
Go to your repo secrets by hitting Settings => Secrets tab in your profile repo. You can also enter the url https://github.com/USERNAME/USERNAME/settings/secrets . Please replace the USERNAME with your own username.

Create a new Secret. Name: TODOIST_API_KEY, Value: Paste the Todoist API Token here. If you don't know what is the token, please go to here to find your API Key there.
```

I didn't understand how to config Settings => Secrets to have Todoist API key.

Thank you so much!

I tried to follow the steps but I don't know how to config Setting > Secrets.

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? Those instructions are fairly clear. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions

Comment: "Create a new Secret. Name: TODOIST_API_KEY, Value: Paste the Todoist API Token here"